# How to redirect logged out users to specific page?

Tags: redirect, logout

I have a question and a technical issue in wordpress. That is, i have a login form on my website to allow visitors to login to see special content. The question goes here, when the time they log in, i am managed to redirect them to a targeted page. When the time they logging out from the member zone, i am out of idea how to send them to a different targeted page.

In my function.php file, I have this code:

```
add_action('wp_logout',create_function('','wp_redirect(home_url());exit();'));
```

How to add the page url that i want to redirect them to this code above?
I am just beginner in php. Hope to get some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`home_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) will accept a parameter that will be used in the creation of the URL.

The bare minimum solution would be:

```
add_action(
  'wp_logout',
  create_function(
    '',
    'wp_redirect(home_url("/path/to/page"));exit();'
  )
);
```

[`site_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) will also accept the same parameter and may be (probably is) a better choice.

I believe that using either of those will make the link dependent on permalink settings. I don't think that those function will translate between different settings, though I have not tested that.

I would suggest using [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url) with an explicit page/post ID.

```
add_action(
  'wp_logout',
  create_function(
    '',
    'wp_redirect("'.get_permalink(1).'");exit();'
  )
);
```

Note that you don't need `home_url()` or `site_url()` since `get_pemalink()` will generate the complete URL.

Comment: Hi You got it work now. Thank you very much! I will remember this guidance. Thank you! =)

Comment: While it is a good idea to remember, you would want to [*accept the answer*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), if it was helpful to you.

Comment: Johannes Pille, excuse me! I did not know about this. But i just did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First i think will be better to

```
add_action('wp_logout',create_function('','wp_redirect(home_url());exit();'));
```

Can instead be replaced to look like this

```
function wpse_109694(){
   $redirect_to = home_url();
   wp_redirect($redirect_to);
   exit();
}

add_action('wp_logout', 'wpse_109694');
```

Once this change is  done , you will see that to redirect to another page of your choice , you just edit the `$redirect_to` variable to the url of the page you need.

Comment: Hansy Schmitt, thank you for your answer, too! But, i am wondering what is the code 'wpse_109694' for? Is that code redirecting user back to the current page after they have logged out? Hope to get your answer soon.

Comment: Actually is the same code you used, but i expanded so it looked easier for you to understand.
In this case , you should only change the variable name `$redirect_to` to match where you want the page to be redirected ( for example , if we take  s_ha_dum sample , i would use $redirect_to = get_permalink(1) or $redirect_to = home_url("/path/to/page")  )

Comment: Lol...i see! Hansy, i tried to use .get_permalink(1) in the code, but it redirected me to a post page instead of previous page where i was. I find no way how to fix that then i have created a logout page where they will be redirected after logged out.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_action('wp_logout',function(){wp_redirect(home_url());exit();});
```

Comment: Please, explain what the code does and how it answers the question. Just dumping code is not a good answer.